# Why are cookies sent with HTML page's cross domain requests but not with JS's XHR?

Tags: web-application, javascript, cookies, html, crossdomain

When we write a `HTML` page with `form` tag and an `action` attribute and a submit button. As soon as we click on submit a request is sent (with cookies) to the `URL` which was the value of `action` attribute.

But if we send cross domain request to the same domain with JS's `XHR` cookies won't be sent.

In both cases, requests are sent to another domain but still cookies are sent with the first case only why so?

Comment: I'm actually having the problem where cookies are not sent along a cross domain form submit, while I was expecting they were. Something has changed on that matter since then ?

Answer (score 5):

Cookies can be send with XHR if [withCredentials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials) is set to true. Contrary to cross-origin form submit or the cross-origin include of resources the application has actually control if cookies are sent or not. Since it is more secure to not include cookies in cross-site requests this is the default and the application has to explicitly enable it if needed.

Answer (score 0):

For the cross-domain form submit, the cookies sending are managed by the [SameSite](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite) setting for each of them.